# HTML file can't connect to socketio

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a fresh HTML file in my file system as shown:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Minimal working example</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        const socket = io("http://localhost:5000", {
            transports: ['websocket']
        });

        socket.on('connect', () => console.log("connect"));
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I also have a javascript socketio server that was run on localhost:

```js
const express = require("express")
const SocketIO = require("socket.io")
const http = require("http")

const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = SocketIO(server)

app.get("/", (_, res) => res.send("Home"))

io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("connection!")
})

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Sever running on ${PORT}`))
```

Why does my server never log anything???

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, but when you open the HTML, is it `file://` or `http://`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's http://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After dwelling in the lands of JavaScript for a long time, I found a solution to this issue which might be helpful to anyone who sees this post.

The solution to this issue was to change the version of socket.io I was using. I am unsure of what version the server was using in the example above. I tried running the same scripts again, but this time using the most up to date and compatible server and client versions of socket.io (`v4.x`). The sockets managed to connect, no matter the protocol (`file:///` or `http://`).

[image]

This is in the socket.io docs [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-installation/). If you want your sockets to connect, make sure the client and server versions are compatible. Because of this, I'm assuming that it was version incompatibility that was the issue when I created this post.

I hope that this post helps someone :D

Answer (score 1):

#### Serve the front end from the same backend

After a bit of a closer inspection, your not serving your HTML file from the same host/port. Chances are your index.html file is getting a CORS error when trying to connect because it is cross origin without approval.

I replaced this line:

```
app.get("/", (_, res) => res.send("Home"))
```

with this line. to serve the index.html file from the same folder (not recommended)

```
app.use(express.static('.'))
```

With both running on the same domain, the connection logged successfully.

Comment: My reason for not using the same host is because I was trying to connect a Java socket.io to this NodeJS server. This is the right solution to this specific issue but what I really need help in is how to connect a Java code (not of the same host/port as the server) to the server. If you could instead give a solution of how to connect any HTML file of any host/port to my server, that'll be of more help :)

Comment: @zS1L3NT Just to be clear, are you trying to connect a Java App using websockets, or HTML served from a Java App?

Comment: I'm trying to connect a Java script, run on any machine, to my server the moment it is executed no matter what host it is on. It could be run from a friend's computer, my computer but both connect to the same NodeJS server

Comment: Then my solution is the one you want. I think the confusion you're having is that other people are on different computers. Those computers connect to the same server, and that is what matters. Not where they connect from, but what they connect to.

Comment: I've tried connecting Java Socket.IO to my NodeJS server but I got "server error" and "xhr poll error". I guessed it was a CORS issue so how can I connect my Java Socket.IO to a NodeJS server?